# primeng editor without toolbar

Tags: editor, toolbar, primeng, quill

How do I switch off the toolbar on a primeNG Editor ?

I am getting the Editor instance of (onInit) of the editor. However the below doesn't seem to work.
The example I see from quilljs all seem to work on the basis of creating a new Quill js instance, but in this case I already have the instance?
The method editorInitComment does get called, but no errors and it still shows the toolbar.

HTML :

```
<p-editor class="quill-comment" [(ngModel)]="comment.body" (onInit)="editorInitComment($event)" [style]="{'height':'90px'}"></p-editor>
```

Typescript :

```
editorInitComment= (event) =>{

  this.quill = event.editor;
  const toolbar = this.quill.getModule('toolbar');

       toolbar : false;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use [InputTextarea](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputtextarea) if you don't want a toolbar ?

Comment: That is a good point, I read somewhere they were using the same text editor to show the comments. But  tbh can't really come up with a reason to do that :). I will try your idea. Thank u

Comment: actually come to think of it, I am trying to reload the content that I saved on a database. So with quilleditor I am saving the detla which I can reload so as that it shows the pictures at the right place etc as it was saved.

Comment: Have you tried to hide it with CSS ?

Comment: The reason I want it without the toolbar and not just a text area is because I don't want it to display styling elements that were already added. <p> <ul> etc.. and have a ngIf that they can click to switch back on the editor.

Answer (score 4):

if you want with proper border use below code.
PrimeNg version:5

[image]

HTML:

```
 <p-editor #editor formControlName="editorValue">
        <p-header> </p-header>    
 </p-editor>
```

CSS:

```
::ng-deep .ql-toolbar.ql-snow {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

::ng-deep .ql-container.ql-snow {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 320px; //pls change height as per your need.
}
```

Comment: This styling worked perfectly for switching between showing and hiding the header!

Answer (score 2):

you can use p-header like this

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="value">
    <p-header hidden>
      <span class="ql-formats"></span>
    </p-header>
  </p-editor>
```

this will show you the header but empty then you can change the css by using ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .ql-toolbar.ql-snow{
 display :none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "p-editor-hide-toolbar" class:

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="myModel" class="p-editor-hide-toolbar">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
   <span class="ql-formats">
     <button type="button" class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>              
  </span>
 </ng-template>
</p-editor>
```

This CSS will hide the tool bar permanently.

```
.p-editor-hide-toolbar {
    .p-editor-container .p-editor-toolbar.ql-snow {
        /* border: 1px solid #dee2e6; */
        display: none;
    }

    .ql-toolbar.ql-snow + .ql-container.ql-snow {
        border-top-color: rgb(222, 226, 230);
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px;
    }
}
```

This CSS will hide the tool bar if you aren't editing it.

```
.p-editor-hide-toolbar:not(:focus-within) {
    .p-editor-container .p-editor-toolbar.ql-snow {
        /* border: 1px solid #dee2e6; */
        display: none;
    }

    .ql-toolbar.ql-snow + .ql-container.ql-snow {
        border-top-color: rgb(222, 226, 230);
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<p-editor formControlName="bodyDetail"  [readonly]="true" [modules]="modules">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" >
    </ng-template>
</p-editor>
```

ts:

```
modules = {
    "toolbar": false
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?